# Blank desktop on booting Tails 2.2 via VM

Tags: tails, linux

I have downloaded Tails ISO tails-i386-2.2.iso and am attempting to boot via VirtualBox.

I am promted to login or select more options, and on logging in a blank blue screen is displayed, possible a blank desktop.

lspci

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

I notice that release 2.0 RC1 "adds support for recent chips such as Intel Broadwell's HD graphics".

http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=09252

Comment: Have you enabled 3d acceleration in the VM's settings?

Comment: Yes I have enabled 3d acceleration